# Destructors and undefined behavior via pointer to base class

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, language-lawyer

Language-lawyer question.

I've just read in Scott Meyerses C++ book that if we try to delete an object through a pointer to a base class without a virtual destructor we'll get UB. Ok, now I'm looking for the explanation of the fact that the behavior is actually undefined. Here's what I've found:

> the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object
>   whose lifetime has ended

and this

> if the object is not of the destructor’s class type and not of a class
>   derived from the destructor’s class type (including when the
>   destructor is invoked via a null pointer value), the program has
>   undefined behavior.

in the section about destructors (`12.4`). But this references don't explain deletion through the base class. Couldn't you provide some explanation in the Standard? Does it actually define that?

Comment: Linked to answer for C++03; it is covered by 5.3.5/3 and the text is still the same in C++14

Comment: @MattMcNabb Cool reference, thank you. Got that.